# How to restrict the domain of a VehicleVar?

Tags: or-tools

I would like to restrict the domain of a vehicle var. For example, stop 1 should be serviced by either vehicle 0 or 1.

Python:

```
n_stops = 11
n_vehicles = 3
ix_depot = 0

index_manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(n_stops, n_vehicles, ix_depot)
routing_model = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(index_manager)
cpsolver = routing_model.solver()

stop = 1
admissible_vehicles = [0, 1]

# missing code here

assignment = routing_model.Solve()
print(assignment.Value(routing_model.VehicleVar(stop)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first you need to get the internal index of the stop node

```
stop_index = index_manager.NodeToIndex(stop)
```

then you get the vehicle var of this node

```
stop_vehicle_var = routing_model.VehicleVar(stop_index)
```

Finally, you can restrict the domain of this variable

```
routing.solver().Add(routing.solver().MemberCt(stop_vehicle_var, [0, 1]))
```

Please note that if you use [0, 1], the node must be performed.
If the node is optional, use [-1, 0, 1] as -1 indicates that the node is unperformed.

Comment: what do you think about `stop_vehicle_var.SetValues([-1, 0, 1])`?

Comment: Should work. It is just that if you set an invalid domain, it will crash, while the MemberCt constraint will cause the model to be infeasible.

Comment: Per default stops are not optional. I make them optional with a disjunction constraint. Is `MemberCt` with `[-1,0,1]` an alternative way to make `stop_index` optional?

Comment: To make them optional, you need a disjunction. But if you remove -1 from the domain of the vehicle var of that node, it cannot be optional.